# How can I make an image change to another image when I click on it

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am making a website and I have run into a problem. I need to make an image change when I click on it and that change it back to the original image when I click again. Can anyone help me with this?

This is the code I have tried so far but it doesn't seem to work for me.

```
<img width="200" height="150" align="right" onclick="changeImg(this, 'Images/Rest2.jpg')" src="Images/Rest2.jpg">
```

```
function changeImg(img, Images/Rest1.jpg) {
    img.src = Images/Rest1.jpg;
}
```

Comment: I have tried this in javascript

function changeImg(img, Images/Rest1.jpg) 
  {
   img.src = Images/Rest1.jpg;
  }  

and added this in the html code

<img width="200" height="150" align="right" onclick="changeImg(this, 'Images/Rest2.jpg')" src="Images/Rest2.jpg">

but its not working

Comment: You should put blocks of code in your original post instead. Plus `function changeImg(img, Images/Rest1.jpg) { ... }` is one big syntax error for the second parameter.

Answer (score 2):

---

### **Updated**

---

```
<html>
<body>
    <img src="foo.jpg" id="myImage">
    <script>
        var myImage = document.querySelector('#myImage');

        myImage.addEventListener('click',function(e) {
            var src = (e.target.src || e.srcElement.src);

            if(src == 'foo.jpg') {
                src = 'bar.jpg';
            } else {
                src = 'foo.jpg';
            }
        },false);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: 'e.target.src||e.srcElement.src' not 'e.src'

Comment: You need to place those image resources in the same folder as the .html file containing the above code (foo.jpg and bar.jpg are place-holders, add real images to them)

Comment: @user2302566 I've upvoted your other answers - so you can upvote now :)

Answer (score 0):

What you're asking for is a 'toggle' function. This example requires that you put an `id` attribute for your `img`.

`<img id="image" ...`

Then use following JS code:

```
document.getElementById('image').onclick = function() {
    if (this.src == 'Images/Rest1.jpg') {
        this.src = 'Images/Rest2.jpg';
    } else if (this.src == 'Images/Rest2.jpg') {
        this.src = 'Images/Rest1.jpg';
    } else {
        alert('error');
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is an idea how you can achieve it using Jquery/JS:

1. Put ur image tag in a div
2. handle onClick event of that div
3. onClick : change image div's source based on currently displayed image.

I hope this helps. you can post your existing code so that can figure out a solution.

Comment: Why would you need to add the extra `</div>`?

Answer (score -1):

Set the current `img` source to a variable, and the second source to another variable. Then change the `src` attribute to your variable, similar to this:

```
<img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/100/sports/"/>
```

```
var source = $('img').attr('src');
var source1 = "http://lorempixel.com/200/100/food/"
$('img').click(function(){
    $(this).attr('src',source1);
    if($(this).attr('src') == source1) $(this).attr('src', source);
});
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/PnezY/)

In my fiddle, it will be a different image each time, because I used lorempixel images as an example, but if you place 2 images, you will get the result you want.

Comment: Seems like down voting is a trend these days. Argue why you down vote, clicka clicka guy!

Answer (score -1):

**Shorthand javascript toggle**

javascript

```
document.getElementById('img').onclick=function(){
 this.src=(this.src=='img1.jpg'?'img2':'img1')+'.jpg';
}
```

where 'img1.jpg' is supposed to be the full link to the image. because even if you just add img1.jpg the browser will parse it as `http://example/img1.jpg`

`console.log(this.src)` inside the function and u get the right path.

html

```
<img id="img" src="img1.jpg">
```

**and if you don't mint to change your code a little, a modern way to do this, but less compatible:**

css3

```
#container{
 width:200px;height:200px;
 background:url('img1.jpg') center center no-repeat;
 background-size:contain;/*or cover or 200px 200px*/
 -webkit-transition:all 700ms ease;/*animation -moz,-ms...*/
}
#container.active{
 background-image:url('img2.jpg');
}
```

js 1.7

```
document.getElementById('container').onclick=function(){
 this.classList.toggle('active');
}
```

html

```
<div id="container"></div>
```

example tested in chrome.

http://jsfiddle.net/6ZMxK/1/

Aaaand if you downvote pls explain why.